# how to check if parameters of 2 instances (one unknown) are the same

Tags: java, constructor, exists

I have already checked similar questions, but none really answered mine.
I may have multiple instances of Tile and i must check with each new construction if there is already an object Tile with the same Coordinate2D. 
Coordinate2D is made up of (int x, int y). 
My questions is, while i create a Tile with a the known Coordinate2D, how do i find out if there already is a Tile with the same object Coordinate2D as a parameter so i can throw a TileExistsException?

```
    public Tile(Coordinate2D coord, int value)throws TileExistsException {      

      this.coord = coord;
      this.value = value;
    }
```

Comment: In a good design you typically wouldn't want it to be the responsibility of Tile class instances to know anything about other instances of the class. Instead, you would have a `Wall` class (or wherever it is you're putting your tiles) which would keep a collection of tiles and guard against duplicates. This way, if in future you decide to have two independent walls, no problem. If it was the responsibility of the Tile class - big problem.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a set of all parameter values used so far and check it in your constructor. It must be `static` so all instances share the same data.

```
private static Set<Coordinate2D> coordinates = new HashSet<>();

public Tile(Coordinate2D coord, int value) throws TileExistsException {
    if (!coordinates.add(coord)) {
        throw new TileExistsException();
    }
    this.coord = coord;
    this.value = value;
}
```

The [`add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-) method of `Set` returns `true` if the set was changed by the operation, so it will return `false` if the coordinate has already been used.

#### Note

For `HashSet` to work, your `Coordinate2D`  class must implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` based on the fields that identify the instance, which I imagine would be `x` and `y`, eg something like:

```
public class Coordinate2D {
    int x;
    int y;
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof Coordinate2D && ((Coordinate2D)o).x == x &&((Coordinate2D)o).y == y;
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(x, y);
    }
    // other methods and fields
}
```

Comment: it seems to get, that this coordinate is already used, but i get a class cast exception.
java.lang.ClassCastException: numbergame.Coordinate2D cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
 at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.cpr(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.doPut(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.putIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet.add(Unknown Source)
 at numbergame.Tile.<init>(Tile.java:20)
 at numbergame.Tile.main(Tile.java:68)

Comment: @D.Hall oops. Just use `HashSet` (threadsafety is another issue not related to this question). See edit. Also note the added caveat.